# google maps custom styling - saturation, lightness do not work

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to use a custom map style on android using google maps android sdk.
Most of the changes and custom styling is being set and working. However setting saturation or lightness on icons do not work - If I try to set saturation or lightness on icons (poi, labels.icon), then the icons disappear entirely.

Removing the saturation and lightness values cause the icons to reappear again.

The json is the one generated from google maps styling wizard(https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com).

This is the exact json I've used:

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e0e0e0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#979797"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "weight": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e7e7e7"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e7e7e7"
      },
      {
        "weight": 0.5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "saturation": -100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.attraction",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#aaaaaa"
      },
      {
        "weight": 0.5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.government",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.medical",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dcedc8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.school",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#c0c0c0"
      },
      {
        "weight": 0.5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "saturation": -100
      },
      {
        "lightness": 65
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#cfcfcf"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station.bus",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station.rail",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#a5cfff"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in Google Maps Android API. It was reported in Google issue tracker some time ago:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65660536

I would suggest starring the bug to add your vote and subscribe to notifications from Google. Hopefully, one day they fix this bug.

#### Update

Google marked this issue as Fixed on October 11, 2018.

This fact is also mentioned in the release notes of the Google Maps Android SDK:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/releases#october_18_2018